# jQuery colon selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

In jQuery there are a few colon selectors like

> :prev, :next, :last

My question is:

1. Are they truly part of jQuery, because they are actually used on DOM elements?
2. We seem to have equivalent methods as well in jQuery `prev()`, `next()`, `last()`. What is the purpose of having 2 different ways?

Any basic examples would be really great.

Comment: I never knew there was a `:prev` or `:next` selector.

Comment: I know `:last` but not `:prev` and `:next`. Are you using some plugin?

Comment: Removed that particular tag..was by mistake..

Comment: This question didn't make sense to me until after I read the accepted answer. (In particular, point (1) doesn't parse well in my brain). Do you think you could edit it to increase readability? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

jQuery does not have `:prev` or `:next` selectors, I have no idea where you came across them. There is a `:last` selector, though, as well as `:first`, provided by the [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com) selector library, used by jQuery. It is a non-standard selector, not part of CSS, and is thus implemented in JavaScript.

One purpose of the `:last` selector over the `.last()` method is so you can use it to filter elements in the middle of a selector sequence, like this (note that `:last` and `:last-child` are not the same):

```
$('.a > .b:last > .c')
```

Rather than having to write a chain of methods like this:

```
$('.a').children('.b').last().children('.c');
```

By the way, the "colon selectors" you refer to are called pseudo-classes (colloquially but incorrectly known as "pseudo-selectors").

Comment: Great answer to a confusing question!

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I made a slider with all sorts of selectors and traversing of objects.

```js
$('#next').click(function () {
  if (!$('*').is(':animated')) {
    if ($('div.display:visible').is(':nth-child(3)')) {

      $('div.display:visible').fadeOut();
      $('div.display:first').fadeIn(function () {
        $(this).children().fadeIn();
      });

    } else {

      $('div.display:visible').fadeOut().next().fadeIn(function () {
        $(this).children().fadeIn();
      });
    }
  }

});

$('#prev').click(function () {
  if (!$('*').is(':animated')) {
    if ($('div.display:visible').is(':nth-child(1)')) {
      $('div.display:visible').fadeOut();
      $('div.display:last').fadeIn(function () {
        $(this).children().fadeIn();
      });

    } else {
      $('div.display:visible').fadeOut().prev().fadeIn(function () {
        $(this).children().fadeIn();
      });
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: Not to my knowledge. They were asking for examples and this has a ton of colon selectors and how I used them.

Answer (score 1):

1. yes, they are in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)
2. sometimes you can't always include everything in the selector or want a subdivision of the selector.

e.g.

```
$(".mylist").each(function(){
  $(this).css("color","red");
  $(this).next().show();
})
```

Comment: Only `:last` is in the documentation, not `:prev` or `:next`.

Comment: @Guffa I interpreted the posters statement *"... selectors like"* to generally include all :selector constructs, and answered the question of why you might use one over the other. (also the link to documentation should amend this)

Answer (score 1):

The colon represents a filter like to get the selected option in a dropdown I would use `$("select option:selected")` or to get a checked radio box I would use `$("input[type=radio]:checked");`

There are no :prev and :next filters, but you can find a full list of filters here http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/